# Why are my CSS Media Query Min & Max-Height properties misfiring?

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm attempting to use media queries to make an image slide up from the bottom of the screen to a point on the screen that is dependant on the screens height.

However, what i'm finding is when I resize the window in Chrome is that the changes are only occurring when the screen size is 0.33 the specified pixel amount and I'm absolutely baffled as to why.

My CSS looks like this:

```
.screen {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -157vw;
    left: 15.5vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    transform: scale(1.3)
}

@media (min-height: 800px) {
    .screen {
        animation: screen800 1300ms;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
}

@media (min-height: 630px) and (max-height: 799px) {
    .screen {
        animation: screen629 1300ms;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
}

@media (max-height: 629px) {
    .screen {
        animation: screen630 1300ms;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
}


@keyframes screen800 {
    from { bottom: -157vw}
    to {bottom: -33vw} 
}

@keyframes screen630 {
    from { bottom: -157vw}
    to {bottom: -56vw}
}

@keyframes screen629 {
    from { bottom: -157vw}
    to {bottom: -68vw}
}
```

I'm not really sure what could be causing this, the code for the media queries must be correct - is it a browswer issue or should I be specifying something in the meta html tags?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You’re probably missing a proper `viewport` meta.

Comment: Agreed with @04FS. Something along the line of `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`